# Set @Html.Textbox() attributes dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This should be pretty straightforward but I'm having a bit of an issue. I'm generating controls dynamically, and each control can have custom html attributes (data-blah="blah", etc...). I figured I could store the attributes in a dictionary then add that dictionary to the html helper in the view.

```
 foreach (var prop in props)
 {
      var PropertyToRender = Model.PropertiesToRender.Where(x => x.Key == prop.Key.Name).ToList();

      if (PropertyToRender.Any())
      {
           var field = PropertyToRender.First().Value;

           if (field.Tag == "input")
           {
                <div class="m-form--group m-form--group-inset">
                     <label>@(prop.Value.Name ?? prop.Key.Name)</label>
                     @Html.TextBox(prop.Key.Name, prop.Key.GetValue(Model), field.Attributes.ToStrng())
                     @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.Key.Name)
                </div>
           }
       }
 }
```

I'm using reflection to get the properties of the model `props`, then a lookup `PropertiesToRender` to see if the model properties need to be rendered. Finally the html attributes are located in `field.Attributes`. I just need a way to render the Html attributes, everything else works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a buffoon - just needed to convert my dictionary into an anonymous object.